# Passing variables in PHP pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-development-server

I have read a value from a form as input form the user. the form is POST.

```
<form action="form_handler.php" method="POST">
```

Then, in the `form_handler.php` page I saved this value in a variable. `$productID=$_POST['product'];`
Then, I want to pass this variable via link to another page as:

```
 echo "<a href='products.php?prodID=".$productID."' title='Products 
 Page' class='whatEver'>click here for product details</a>";
```

When I click the link, I see the value in the link. But, inside the page `products.php` I want to make MySQL query for the product details as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodID = '$productID'";
```

I get 0 results. I also tried to echo the $productID value and it seems empty and not the value that I saw in the URL.

What is my mistake please? How can I make the database query to fetch the product details based on the productID variable I passed in the link?

NOTE: I am trying to make a demo for MySQL injection vulnerability. Please, ignore security issues here.

Comment: are you catching the value of `$_GET['prodID']; ` inside `products.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get like that the productID .. You have to put `$productID = $_GET['prodID']; ' the you can use that variable with sql query .

Answer (score 0):

When you sent variables in a link followed by `?var=value`

You need to get it with something like

`$variable = $_GET['var'];`

In your case your products.php
should have `$prodid = $_GET['prodID'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='products.php?prodID=".$productID."' title='Products 
Page' class='whatEver'>click here for product details</a>";
```

Looks to me like you are passing it into products.php as `prodID`.
Could you try using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodID = '$prodID'";
```

Instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just like before when you used `$productID=$_POST['product'];`,
you need to do the same thing to use a variable in products.php, except instead of a post variable, it's a get variable (because it's in the url). Use `$productID=$_GET["productID"]`